# Get the member id from database 

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the memberid corresponding to text enter into the textbox like this

```
SELECT member_Id FROM members WHERE concat(member_Firstname,'',member_Lastname) = S Thwaites
```

but it gives an error like this
"Error Code: 1064

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;  
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
use near 'WHERE concat(member_Firstname,'',member_Lastname) = 'S Thwaites'' 
at line 1"
```

I am using MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with

```
SELECT member_Id FROM members WHERE concat(member_Firstname,'',member_Lastname) = 'S Thwaites'
```

Comment: @"SELECT member_Id FROM members WHERE concat(member_Firstname,'',member_Lastname) =" + tbMemberName.Text; I am using this one would you pls help me out with  this statement

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a column name on the other side of the equal sign. Like this:

```
select member_id from members where member_Firstname='S' and member_Lastname ='Thwaites';
```

You have to have two text boxes, one for first name and one for last name.

Here's a good SQL tutorial: http://www.sql-tutorial.net/

Then you may want to take a look at MySQL's documentation because the SQL syntax differs slightly from one database to another.